# Assign array to a different variable

Tags: c, arrays, variables

Here is a part of my code

```
int river(int a[], int n){
  int sorted[] = a;
}
```

n being the size of the array

I have tried a couple of different ways, including

```
sorted[n]
```

but I get problems each time. 
What I am trying to do is duplicate the array with a changed variable name. The array will be exactly the same, just stored in a different variable (because I want to obtain information but not modify the original array).

Is this just not possible because of something to do with dynamically changing the size of the array, or am I just missing the point?

Thanks!

Comment: That's what `memcpy` is for. " I want to obtain information but not modify the original array" -- wait ... then why do you want to copy it? Just use the original array.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, arrays are not assignable. You can either copy the contents of one array into another, or get a pointer to the first element of the array. For example

```
int a[42] = {0};
int* b = a;      // now you can access a's elements as b[0], b[1], etc.
int c[42];
memcpy(c, a, 42*sizeof(int)); //copy elements of a into c
```

Second, you should note that the function signature

```
int foo(int a[]);
```

is another way of saying

```
int foo(int* a);
```

i.e. it can take any pointer to int, even ones that don't point to arrays.

With that in mind, you can see that you easily lose array size information, which is why you need to pass the size as a parameter:

```
int foo(int a[], size_t n);

int a[42];
foo(a, 42);
```

Now, inside the function, you can copy the elements of one array into another:

```
int foo(int* a, size_t n)
{
  int sorted[n];
  memcpy(sorted, a, n * sizeof(int));
  // use sorted
  ....
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1+, but nitpicking: `int n` should be `size_t n` or even better `const size_t n`

Comment: @alk Agreed. I was just basing it on OP's signature. But I'll change that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for the new copy of array by yourself.

```
int *sorted = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
memcpy(sorted, a, n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: So it is a problem with memory allocation, interesting. Thank you very much!

Comment: `int sorted[n]; memcpy(sorted, a, n * sizeof *a);` -- works too (if you're using a modern C compiler that supports C99 or later).

Answer (score 1):

Simply try like this...

```
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     sorted[i]=a[i];
```

If you want to use dynamic memory allocation `malloc` , try this

```
     int *sorted = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
     memcpy(sorted, a, n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was trying more so to understand why my implementation wasn't working. Thanks for the help, however!

Comment: Whether the array is dynamically allocated or not isn't relevant to whether to use `memcpy` or a loop ... both work in either case.